# which part of windows loads mscoree.dll?

Tags: windows, dll, operating-system

I know that .Net framework runtime is contained in mscoree.dll.Can anyone help me in knowing which part of windows operating system or which process of windows loads this dll into the memory.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on `windows 7` you can use the `Resource Monitor`. Within your `Task Manager` in the tab `Performance`. At the bottom there is the button for the `Resource Monitor`.

In the tab `CPU` you can select which processes to monitor.
Select all and sort the `Handles` for their name.
Now you should see which `running processes` are using your `dll`.

Comment: Is there any way to know in windows xp?

Comment: Try the [process explorer](http://www.heise.de/software/download/process_explorer/21841) (should be quitely the same)

Comment: **More detail:** Expand ***Associated Modules*** and click on the ***Module Name*** column to sort by the DLL and EXE names.